# nginx won't load site on local machine

Tags: nginx, localhost

I want to build and test my website on my Arch Linux computer.

The contents of the website, including `index.html`, are in `/srv/http/myproject/`.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.conf` looks like this...

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /srv/http/myproject;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name myproject.local;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }    
}
```

UPDATE: I had already ran `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject.conf`.

And `/etc/hosts` has this...

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.local
```

But when I navigate to `http://myproject.local/`, all I see is the "Welcome to nginx" page.

Comment: Please be more specific about `won't connect`. What is the exact error message you encounter? And did you create a symlink to your .conf in `sites-enabled`?

Comment: You need to create a `server` block for the hostname you are trying to use.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How must that code look in this case?

Comment: `server_name the_real_name;`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When I replaced `server_name myproject.local` with `server_name myproject` in the `server ` block that changed nothing.

Comment: Again, you need to use the actual hostname that you are trying to connect to.

Comment: I'm testing this site on my local machine so assuming everything is in the folder `myproject`, how should my `server ` block look?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable the website.

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject.conf
```

And the ofcourse, restart/reload nginx.

Comment: Forgot to mention I already ran that. Updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: You have added "myproject.local" to your hostfile, and added "myproject.local" as a servername - but you are trying to navigate to "http://predictit-monitor.local/" ?

Comment: Whoops, updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

How about just `127.0.0.1 myproject.local` in the /etc/hosts?
In my experience it would not necessary the semicolon in the end of line

Comment: Updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to include `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in the `http` block of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.